# On clicking submit button unable to post or submit my file into server

Tags: angular, typescript, post

I wanted to post a csv file after clicking submit button. But while clicking submit button its giving error stating that the selected file is not added as request into post command. Please help. The following is the code snippet for my functions of selecting and submitting the file in to server

```
fileChangeListener($event) {
    var text = [];
    var files = $event.target.files;

    if (appConstants.validateHeaderAndRecordLengthFlag) {
      if (!this.appService.isCSVFile(files[0])) {
        this.errorMessage = "Please import valid .csv file.";
        this.isFail = true;
        this.fileReset();
        return;
      }
    }

    var input = $event.target;
    let url = "/uploadInspectionReport";
    let token = this.appService.getToken();
    if (token) {
      console.log("file getting", input.files[0])
      this.gettingFile = input.files[0]
      this.buttonStatus = false
    } (err) => {
      console.log("******** Error in uploading inspection records: *********");
      console.log(err);
      this.errorMessage = err;
      this.isFail = true;
    }
}

submitFile(File) {
    //this.confirmationDialogService.confirm('Please confirm..', 'Do you really want to ... ?')
    //.then((confirmed) => console.log('User confirmed:', confirmed))
    //.catch(() => console.log('User dismissed the dialog (e.g., by using ESC, clicking the cross icon, or clicking outside the dialog)'));
    let url = "/uploadInspectionReport";
    let token = this.appService.getToken();
    if (token) {
      this.appService
        .postCsv(url, token, File)
        .subscribe(
          result => {
            console.log("******** Uploaded inspection records *********");
            this.isFileUploaded = true;
            this.csvUploadMessage = result.statusMessage;
          }
        );
    } (err) => {
      console.log("******** Error in uploading inspection records: *********");
      console.log(err);
      this.errorMessage = err;
      this.isFail = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the postCsv method? I m thinking your error is because the headers that you use to send the file

Comment: I have made it right by a small change in my code in the following line 
.postCsv(url, token, this.gettingFile)